# Microsoft Access: Cannot add record(s); join key of 'Customer' not in recordset

Tags: ms-access

This is how my relationship looks like:
[Relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJdHS.png)

and this is my form:
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsAxz.png)

The main problem I've been having so far as my teacher told me was with my relationships so I made it extremely simple as shown in the screenshot above. However, after creating the form I get this error message in the bottom on my screen saying, "Cannot add record(s); join key of 'Customer' not in recordset."

- **Note:** I'm new to Access and know little to nothing about it.
- **Note:** Access 2007 - 2013 file format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is most likely bound to a join query of Customer and Show tables. If so, you must explicitly add `Customer.Show_ID` as a column in that query. Then, that combobox's control source should be the newly added `Customer.Show_ID` field.

In fact, to avoid confusion simply leave out `Show.[Show ID]` to avoid confusion. And usually you want to keep one primary key and any needed foreign keys per recordset. Here, `Show.[Show ID]` is a primary key and `Customer.Show_ID` is the foreign key.

Or better yet, bound the entire Customer form to only the Customer table and not query as the combo box already looks up the values in `Show.[Show Date]` regardless of the form's bounded recordset.